# Retrieving friends' interests, political

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried in vain to find the right answer.
I have tried:

```
    try{
      //$fql    =   "SELECT name,political,activities,interests,movies FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";       
        $fql    =   "SELECT name,political,activities,interests,movies,books,quotes,about_me FROM user WHERE uid = ".$abc;
       $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $friendProfileInfo = $facebook->api($param);
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
       d($o);
    }
```

and i have tried this too:

```
     $friendProfileInfo = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,political,activities');
```

i have already declared the required permissions:

```
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'user_groups,user_about_me,user_religion_politics,user_interests,friends_groups,friends_interests,friends_religion_politics,friends_about_me',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);
```

yet i am getting only the id, name as return values. please help.

Comment: I am having the exact issue. Did you ever get this figured out? I think this is a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not able to reproduce
I ran `fql?q=SELECT political,activities FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

And here's some results:

```
{
  "political": "Aleister Crowley 2012 (Other people are not your property)",
  "activities": "Invisible Pink Unicorn, Amatuer radio, Sound Engineering, Ice hockey, Child, Shooting"
}, 

{
  "political": null,
  "activities": "Sailing, Hiking, Mountain biking, Camping, Kayaking, Snorkeling, Walking on the Beach With Andrea"
}, 

{
  "political": "Moderate conservative",
  "activities": "McRib, Road trips, And Poking Dead Things With a Stick, Long Walks on the Beach"
},
```

Be sure to check your access token with the linter to ensure you have the correct permissions: `friends_activities` and `friends_religion_politics`

Here's the results from my access token when run thru the linter (bad copy paste, but you get the idea):

> Issued:    1324594818 : 3:00 pm Dec 22 2011 
>   Expires:   Never 
>   Valid:    True
>   Origin:   Web
>   scopes:  ads_management create_event create_note email export_stream
>   friends_about_me friends_activities friends_birthday friends_checkins
>   friends_education_history friends_events friends_games_activity
>   friends_groups friends_hometown friends_interests friends_likes
>   friends_location friends_location_posts friends_notes
>   friends_online_presence friends_photo_video_tags friends_photos
>   friends_questions friends_relationship_details friends_relationships
>   friends_religion_politics friends_status friends_subscriptions
>   friends_videos friends_website friends_work_history manage_friendlists
>   manage_notifications manage_pages offline_access photo_upload
>   publish_checkins publish_stream read_friendlists read_insights
>   read_mailbox read_requests read_stream rsvp_event share_item sms
>   status_update user_about_me user_activities user_birthday
>   user_checkins user_education_history user_events user_games_activity
>   user_groups user_hometown user_interests user_likes user_location
>   user_location_posts user_notes user_online_presence
>   user_photo_video_tags user_photos user_questions
>   user_relationship_details user_relationships user_religion_politics
>   user_status user_subscriptions user_videos user_website
>   user_work_history video_upload xmpp_login